# MVVM - Viewmodels in Datagrid rows?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel

i want to write a little programm to manage article.
the pgm should show a list of article in a datagrid.

the can be 500/1000 articles that must be displayed in the grid.
Should i use viewmodels in the datagrid rows like josh smith does in his example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx ?

i tested a little bit in joshs example.
so i took his customers.xml file and extended it to 800 customers.
-> the app took a little (more)time to start and closing it (if show click the "show all customer" button) will take a few seconds. So it should be a heavy load for the system using viewmodels ?
can someone explain me the advantage using viewmodels as datagrid rows instead of articles?

What is the better way ?

```
public ObservableCollection<ArticleViewModel> AllArticle { get; private set; }
```

or

```
public ObservableCollection<Article> AllArticleraw { get; private set; }
```

Comment: if this is small project and your concerns are about performance and time, then MVVM would be overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not to use ViewModels as your DataGrid Rows really depends on how much functionality each row must have.

If the grid is read-only, for display purposes only, and the underlying data will not change, then ViewModels would probably be overkill for a row.

However, if your user may interact with the row, perhaps edit values in a row, or if values in the row may change as a result of an external action, and you want those changes to reflect automatically in the grid, then you should consider ViewModels.

And keep in mind that a ViewModel is just a name for an object that serves a purpose - it can be as heavy or as light as you need it to be.  For example, if you want your row to reflect changes in the grid immediately, it can be a simple POCO that has properties for each row column, and then implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the grid when one of those property values has changed.

Don't let heavy-weight implementations of ViewModels scare you away from the concepts of MVVM - implement only the features you need in each ViewModel.

Comment: Question: If using viewmodels in a datagrid, can the datagrid create new viewmodels like it was adding a row?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on this, but I don't think the WPF DataGrid will create a new ViewModel for you.  What I normally do is have a separate button for adding a new item, give them a view to provide the details of the new item and then when they're done, save the item and add it to the collection underlying the DataGrid. If you want to stay inside the grid, I would recommend looking at the AddingNewItem and EndRowEditing [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events(v=vs.110).aspx) of the DataGrid where you could create your own ViewModel.